# How to get a random element of array of images and display it

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, display

I've tried to do something like this but I haven't had any success. I'm not sure if this is the correct syntax

```
<p id = "Person"></p>
var x = <img src="bob.jpg"  width = "500" height = "500">
var y = <img src="joe.jpg"  width = "500" height = "500">
var z = <img src="chad.jpg"  width = "500" height = "500">
```

Try to pick out a random image from an array

```
var myArray = [ x, y,  z ];

var randomNumber = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
```

Then how do I display it? Is there another document. that i'm supposed to use?

```
document.getElementById("Person").innerHTML = randomNumber
```

Comment: @slacker When If I make that the array, where does the src go for those images? Before when I tried to do that and make the images straight in the array it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this simple way.

```js
const myArray = ["bob.jpg", "joe.jpg", "chat.jpg"]
const randomImage = () => {
 const image = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]; // 0 -> 2
 console.log(image);
 document.getElementById("Person").innerHTML = `<img src="${image}" width="500" height="500" />`;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="randomImage()">Random Image</button>
<p id = "Person"></p>
```

Comment: Yes your comment helped answer my question I figured out how to ouput the image as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your case the only thing changing is the image name, it'd be easier to store that in the array as strings.

```
var myArray = ['bob.jpg', 'joe.jpg', 'chad.jpg'];
```

And then use your random picker to select the image to show as this:

```
var randomlySelectedImage = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
document.getElementById('Person').innerHTML = 
  `<img src="${randomlySelectedImage}" width="500" height="500" />`;
```